# subgraph resolve error: Serialization error: missing field `name`

Tags: solidity, the-graph, subgraph

I'm going though [Patrick's solidity course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyMwXuJrbJQ&t=59656s). I'm on 28:36:52.
I'm trying to deploy my subgraph and I'm getting this error.

```
✖ Failed to deploy to Graph node https://api.studio.thegraph.com/deploy/: subgraph resolve error: resolve error: Serialization error: missing field `name` at line 216 column 3
```

Can someone explain me what does this error mean and how to resolve it.

This is my 216 line on generated/schema.ts

```
line 215                         get nftAddress(): Bytes {
line 216                              let value = this.get("nftAddress");
line 217                              return value!.toBytes();
                                 }
```

And Nftmarketplace abi under build folder has name `getProceeds` near line 216. What's wrong?

Everything is auto generated like schema or build folder so they can't be wrong. I have tried deleting and doing everything 2-3 times. But it's not working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue. I believe it's an ABI error. When I Initialized my subgraph I hadn't verified my contract on etherscan so i couldn't get the ABI automatically, thus, I had to add the json file manually. For some reasons, the ABI when pulled from etherscan is configured differently (for lack of a better word) when compared to manual json file.

It worked after I verified my contract on etherscan and  `graph init --studio marketplace-nft` was able to pull the ABI from etherscan.

PS: compare the automatic generated ABI json file to the manual json file to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and realized the ABI I had given was not in the correct format. The field `"name"` was missing in the output parameters of all function interfaces.
I re-generated the ABI with the missing fields and it solved the problem.